# Force file history associations with Git

Tags: git

I refactored a project, moving files into different directories and splitting modules into multiple submodules, so my file architecture is now completely different from what it used to be.

Is there a way that I can tell git which files it thinks were deleted are actually simply the new files? I know that git is supposed to determine this automatically if I move and rename in separate commits, but I've already done the refactoring and wouldn't want to redo it all.

In short, I'd love a command like:

```
git associate /path/to/deleted_file /path/to/new_file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, no. Some Git subcommands take flags that will attempt to more aggressively track renames and copies. For example, `git log` has a `--follow` flag to follow a file across a rename. Several commands have `-M` and `-C` flags which attempt to more aggressively find renames and copies; these flags take a optional value to specify a threshold for what should be considered a rename or copy. Some subcommands even have a `--find-copies-harder` that can more aggressively calculate renames and copies.

But in general, no. Git doesn't actually track whether you copied or renamed a file—it just tracks content.

Comment: Hmm, that sucks. I can't imagine it would be that hard to add to git!